# Storing object reference into a volatile field

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I'm using the following field:

```
private DateDao dateDao;

private volatile Map<String, Date> dates;

public Map<String, Date> getDates() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(dates);
}

public retrieveDates() {
     dates = dateDao.retrieveDates();
}
```

Where

```
public interface DateDao {
    //Currently returns HashMap instance
    public Map<String, Date> retrieveDates();
}
```

Is it safe to publish the map of dates that way? I mean, volatile field means that the reference to a field won't be cached in CPU registers and be read from memory any time it is accessed.

So, we might as well read a stale value for the `state of the map` because `HashMap` doesn't do any synchronization.

Is it safe to do so?

UPD: For instance assume that the DAo method implemented in the following way:

```
public Map<String, Date> retrieveDates() {
    Map<String, Date> retVal = new HashMap<>();
    retVal.put("SomeString", new Date());
    //ad so forth...
    return retVal;
}
```

As can be seen, the Dao method doesn't do any synchronization, and both `HashMap` and `Date` are mutable and not thread safe. Now, we've created and publish them as it was shown above. Is it guaranteed that any subsequent read from the `dates` from some another thread will observe not only the correct reference to the `Map` object, but also it's "fresh" state.

I'm not sure about if the thread can't observe some stale value (e.g. `dates.get("SomeString")` returns `null`)

Comment: "Safe" in what sense? That a call to `getDates` will always see the most-recently assigned map from `retrieveDates`? Or...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder _That a call to getDates will always see the most-recently assigned map from_ Why do you think so? Without synchronization `JIT` is allowed to perfrom any optimization that is compatitible with Memory Model. Creating and filling the Map in Dao doesn't involve any syncrhonization as well as HashMap is not thread safe. I'm a little worried about that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My question in fact is. Is it really sufficient to just store a reference to an object which is not going to be modified into a `volatile` field to publish it safely? Even if creating and some other opertaion on the object before publishing  doesn't entail synchronization.

Comment: I was asking what you're asking, not asserting anything. To clarify your question, use the "edit" link on the question, not comments.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Done, couldn't you look at it?

Comment: Just an English language FYI: "Could you look at it?" is a request that someone look at something. "*Couldn't* you look at it?" is a complaint that they didn't. :-) (Crazy language, eh?) I'll take a look, but I may not have the depth of knowledge on this to answer (just to identify that more detail was needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking two questions:

1. Given that DAO code, is it possible for your code using it to use the object reference it gets here:

   ```
    dates = dateDao.retrieveDates();
   ```

**before** the `dateDao.retrieveDates` method as quoted is done adding to that object. E.g., do the memory model' statement reordering semantics allow the `retrieveDates` method to return the reference before the last `put` (etc.) is complete?

2. Once your code has the `dates` reference, is there an issue with unsynchronized access to `dates` in your code and also via the read-only view of it you return from `getDates`.

Whether your field is `volatile` has no bearing on either of those questions. The only thing that making your field `volatile` does is prevent a thread calling `getDates` from getting an out-of-date value for your `dates` field. That is:

```
Thread A                                       Thread B
----------                                     --------
1. Updates `dates` from dateDao.retrieveDates
2. Updates `dates` from " " again
3.                                             getDates returns read-only
                                               view of `dates` from #1
```

Without `volatile`, the scenario above is possible (but harmless). With `volatile`, it isn't, Thread B will see the value of `dates` from #2, not #1.

But that doesn't relate to either of the questions I think you're asking.

#### Question 1

No, your code in `retrieveDates` cannot see the object reference returned by `dateDao.retrieveDates` before `dateDao.retrieveDates` is done filling in that map. The [memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) allows reordering statements, but:

> ...compilers are allowed to reorder the instructions in either thread, **when this does not affect the execution of that thread in isolation**

*(My emphasis.)* Returning the reference to your code before `dateDao.retrieveDates` would obviously affect the execution of the thread in isolation.

#### Question 2

The DAO code you've shown can never modify the map it returns to you, since it doesn't keep a copy of it, so we don't need to worry about the DAO.

In *your* code, you haven't shown anything that modifies the contents of `dates`. If your code doesn't modify the contents of `dates`, then there's no need for synchronization, since the map is unchanging. You might want to make that a guarantee by wrapping `dates` in the read-only view when you *get* it, rather than when you return it:

```
dates = Collection.unmodifiableMap(dateDao.retrieveDates());
```

If your code *does* modify `dates` somewhere you haven't shown, then yes, there's potential for trouble because `Collections.unmodifiableMap` does nothing to synchronize map operations. It just creates a read-only view.

If you wanted to ensure synchronization, you'd want to wrap `dates` in a [`Collections.synchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-) instance:

```
dates = Collections.synchronizedMap(dateDao.retrieveDates());
```

Then all access to it in your code will be synchronized, and all access to it via the read-only view you return will also be synchronized, as they all go through the synchronized map.

Comment: The concept of obeying intra-thread semantic is quite blurred.... _Returning the reference to your code before dateDao.retrieveDates would obviously affect the execution of the thread in isolation._ Is it because of the volatile reference?

Comment: @Alupkers It kind of depends really. If, for instance, the JIT wants to re-order the assignment of `dates = dateDao.retrieveDates();` outside of the `retireveDates` then the JIT is violating intra-thread semantics because a `getDates` call prior to an initial `retireveDates` call should fail but in that case would not.

Comment: @Alupkers: *"Is it because of the volatile reference?"* No, it's because if we just look at that one thread, ignoring any others, it would obviously be a big difference in the action of that thread if your code received `dates` and possibly went on to access the map when `dateDao.retrieveDates` was still writing to the map. Since that's a big difference (and potentially would introduce a `ConcurrentModificationException`), the JIT isn't allowed to do that. And since it's not allowed to do that within the thread, it can't do it when there are multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, declaring a map `volatile` won't synchronize its access (i.e. readers could read the map while it is being updated by the dao). However, it guarantees that the map lives in shared memory, so every thread will see the same values in it at every given time. What I usually do when I need synchronization and freshness is using a lock object, something similar to the following :

```
private DateDao dateDao;
private volatile Map<String, Date> dates;
private final Object _lock = new Object();

public Map<String, Date> getDates() {
   synchronized(_lock) {
     return Collections.unmodifiableMap(dates);
   }
}

public retrieveDates() {
   synchronized(_lock) {
     dates = dateDao.retrieveDates();
   }
}
```

This provides readers/writers synchronization (but note that writers are not prioritized, i.e. if a reader is getting the map the writers will have to wait) and 'data freshness' via `volatile`. Moreover, this is a pretty basic approach, and there are other ways of achieving the same features (e.g. `Lock`s and `Semaphores`), but most of the times this does the trick for me.

Comment: *"However, it guarantees that the map lives in shared memory, so every thread will see the same values in it at every given time."* No, it guarantees that the **reference** to it in `dates` will be consistent across threads. It does nothing, at all, with regard to the state of the object that reference refers to.

Comment: Hey @T.J.Crowder thanks for the clarification! So basically volatile guarantees only that the referenced 
object hasn't been substituted, not that its state hasn't changed? I guess that in order to guarantee that the state is consistent across threads I need an immutable object, is that the only way of achieving it?

Comment: Right, `volatile` refers to the *variable*, not the thing it refers to.

Comment: Well, could you explain static in the lock declaration? IF we have 1000 objects, for instance...

Comment: You are right, static is not needed in this case. Sorry, my mistake (`static` was there because I use this approach also for Singletons, and in that case it is needed because the `getInstance` method has to be static).